# Is there any standard Poller example class in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, polling

Is there any good example of poller class? Thread safe with wait handles, with background/foreground options and common start, stop, pause, resume calls?

I found examples like [CruiseControl poller](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Build-Systems/CruiseControl.NET/ThoughtWorks/CruiseControl/CCTrayLib/Monitoring/Poller.cs.htm) but ideally I would like to avoiding implementing IPollable every time I want to poll for something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a standard one other than the basic .NET timer class, but here's a wrapper class for the .NET timer that uses a delegate rather than the IPollable interface of the wrapper you found. it also features a bit of locking and some methods that come in handy. you may want to extend and improve it yourself for pause/resume and logging, for example. good luck.

```
public class TimerWrapper
{
    private object defaultLock = new object();
    private object functionLock = null;
    private object classLock = new object();
    protected bool isRunning = false;
    protected bool isRepeating = false;
    protected Timer timer = null;
    protected Action timerFn = null;

    public TimerWrapper(Action timerFn)
    {
        if (timerFn == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timerFn", "Invalid timer delegate supplied at construction");
        }
        // Execute this function upon expiration of the timer
        this.timerFn = timerFn;
    }

    public TimerWrapper(Action timerFn, ref object timerLock) : this(timerFn)
    {
        // Use the locking object passed at construction
        this.functionLock = timerLock;
    }

    protected void TimerFunction(object state)
    {
        if (timerFn != null)
        {
            lock (classLock)
            {
                // Lock on function lock if available or default lock otherwise
                lock (functionLock ?? defaultLock)
                {
                    // If timer isn't repeating it's now no longer running
                    if (!IsRepeating)
                    {
                        IsRunning = false;
                    }

                    // Execute this function because timer has expired
                    timerFn();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (classLock)
        {
            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.Dispose();
                timer = null;
            }

            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void Start(int duetime)
    {
        // Start the timer for a single run
        Start(duetime, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Start(int duetime, int period)
    {
        if (duetime > 0)
        {
            lock (classLock)
            {
                // Stop the timer
                Stop();

                // Start the timer for either a single run or repeated runs
                timer = new Timer(TimerFunction, null, duetime, period);

                IsRunning = true;
                IsRepeating = (period != Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRepeating
    {
        get
        {
            return isRepeating;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (isRepeating != value)
            {
                isRepeating = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return isRunning;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (isRunning != value)
            {
                isRunning = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks mtijn, looked at your example and wrote my own poller which does all what a poller is supposed to be doing. Any comments are appreciated.

```
public class Poller
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Poller));

    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly int _pollingInterval;
    private readonly Thread _processingThread;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _stopEvent;
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _pauseEvent;
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();
    private PollerState _pollerState;

    public Poller(string pollerName, Action action, int pollingInterval, bool isBackground)
    {
        _action = action;
        _pollingInterval = pollingInterval;

        _stopEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _pauseEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        _processingThread = new Thread(DoWork) { IsBackground = isBackground, Name = pollerName };

        _pollerState = PollerState.Unstarted;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _pollerState = PollerState.Running;
        _processingThread.Start();
    }

    public void Start(int dueTime)
    {
        new Timer(o => Start(), null, dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            if (_pollerState != PollerState.Running && _pollerState != PollerState.PauseRequested)
                _log.WarnFormat("Requested STOP on {0} poller state.", _pollerState);

            _pollerState = PollerState.StopRequested;
            _stopEvent.Set();
            _pauseEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            if (_pollerState != PollerState.Running)
                _log.WarnFormat("Requested PAUSE on {0} poller state.", _pollerState);

            _pauseEvent.Reset();
            _pollerState = PollerState.PauseRequested;
        }
    }

    public void Continue()
    {
        lock(_syncLock)
        {
            if (_pollerState == PollerState.PauseRequested)
                _pollerState = PollerState.Running; // applicable if job is long running or no new poll was needed since pause requested
            else if (_pollerState != PollerState.Paused)
                _log.WarnFormat("Requested CONTINUE on {0} poller state.", _pollerState);
            _pauseEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (_pollerState == PollerState.Running)
        {
            try
            {
                _action();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "failed.", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_stopEvent.WaitOne(_pollingInterval))
                {
                    if (_pollerState == PollerState.StopRequested)
                        _pollerState = PollerState.Stopped;
                }

                if (_pollerState == PollerState.PauseRequested)
                {
                    _pollerState = PollerState.Paused;
                    _pauseEvent.Wait();
                    // Continue only if we are still in Pause mode and not StopRequested
                    if (_pollerState == PollerState.Paused)
                        _pollerState = PollerState.Running;
                }
            }
        }
        _log.Debug("Exiting: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
}
public enum PollerState
{
    Unstarted = 0,
    Running = 1,
    StopRequested = 2,
    Stopped = 3,
    PauseRequested = 4,
    Paused = 5,
}
```

Comment: ok then: you could use reflection to set the poller name to the function or class or thread name of the caller, that saves you a poller name argument. you could also initialize the logger with that info in the ctor. to increase the reusability of your poller you may want to move setting the polling interval to the start method(s). the start methods are currently not thread safe. and finally, if this were my poller I'd want to see exceptions of the invoked action rather than swallowing them. does all this answer your question? if so please mark the answer.

Comment: thanks for reply, I like my own names since they are short but it is a nice idea to use reflection there - will try and see how does it looks in logs.
You are right missed lock statement on start but still issue with duetime overload - unfortunately ThreadStateException will be thrown if called twice

I have my own catch blocks within action to handle communication exceptions differently and so on if needed. I do not want exception to stop my poller.

Comment: btw, you're not disposing the timer. and I'm not sure if starting the thread twice in the default Start method is going to work without stopping it first. and you're not waiting for your thread to finish anywhere, so there's no guarantee it's finished yet before you call Start again. I think I'd just create a new thread object on Start, I think I had the same exception before when I didn't.

Comment: I never thought I could stop and start the poller again, I do not have a such a case scenario but it would make threapool more generic, Thread could not be readonly anymore

- there is no need to dispose timer because there is none

Comment: update on this class - have you made any improvements or tweaks?